# The meaning of " a class of disjoint sets, denoted hom(A,B), ..."

Tags: meaning

I'm studying a math book. There is a definition as seen below.

> A **category** is a class C of objects (denoted a,b,c ...) together with 
> (i) a class of disjoint sets, denoted hom(a,b), one for each pair of objects in C...
> (ii) ...

I want to ask which one of the following meanings should be deduced from this statement regarding the grammer rules;

1. hom(a,b) is one of the sets of a class.
2. hom(a,b) is a class of disjoint sets.

*The whole thing may confuse you so please just consider the part saying: " a class of disjoint sets, denoted hom(a,b), one for each pair of objects in C..."*

Comment: [[A]] It is (1) : "hom(A,B)" is "one of the Disjoint sets of the class" , where A & B are "placeholders" where we have to put in a,b,c etc. [[B]] If you want to know about the grammar , it is ok to Post it here. If you want to know about the Maths , you should Post it elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but your warning is just meaningless, because it is already written in my post that I am looking for a grammatical answer to my question not a math related one.

Comment: I did not see that post, thanks a a lot @Graffito. Actually a more related one is [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4741545/t-w-hungerford-graduate-text-in-mathematics-algebra-definition-7-1) which has been raised by myself. In my opinion the confusion is caused by the poor use of English language at the very specific point that I've mentioned above, however English is not my native language and so I carry the question here to get some help from experts.

Comment: I’m voting to acknowledge that math uses language that is compact by nature. In English, we'd prefer a few words added for clarity:  (i) a class of disjoint sets "that are" denoted "as" hom(a,b).

Comment: The question is not related with math. To show this I rewrite my question as "A capcup is a is a class of thinks (denoted as a,b,c …) together with a class of red apples, denoted as pepake(a,b). According to this sentence which one is correct (A) pekape(a,b) is a red apple or (B) pekape(a,b) is a class of red apples." This sentence asks exactly the same thing.

Comment: @Sel Yes, this is confusing because both 'class' and 'set' are kinds of collections. But English syntax and commas (or parens)  say that 1) "A 'category' is a group of things, denoted hom(A,B), ..." means that the category is denoted 'hom(A,B). Whereas 2) "A 'category' is a group of things denoted hom(A,B) ..."means the -things- are denoted hom(A,B).

Comment: I asked the stack team but they could not support an answer. Is there anybody who can prove that this post is "opinion-based".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're only focusing on grammar (syntax), then the parent of the past participle phrase "denoted hom(A,B)" is unclear; it could be either "disjoint sets" (in which case it could refer to the disjoint sets severally or as a whole) or "a class of disjoint sets". This is a kind of "[syntactic ambiguity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_ambiguity)", and if you search for that term on this site, then you'll find several other examples.

Comment: There's also the problem that objects of the set are denoted as small letters, but A and B are capital letters. What does that mean? hom(A,B) is not defined since A and B are not.

Comment: That is my mistake. I altered the curly C that represents the category to regular capital C because I could not figure out how to use the latex in this post. Hence I altered A,B,C… as a,b,c… but apparently I forget to change it in hom(A,B) part. I will edit it now.